# Reactjs update app in real time across multitple host

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

How to update a react app/component in real time across multiple host machines(browsers)?

I have a MERN app with NodeJS running on my localhost on port 8888 and MongoDB running on MongoDB Atlas. I opened two different browsers and tried inserting data to the DB. The app updated and displayed the latest content on one browser and it didn't update on the other one.

This snapshot here is the updated data ("Checking live response") on one browser
[image]

while this snapshot is from other browser which did not update.
[image]

How to handle this situation?

Comment: Hey Sam, those kinds of updates don't happen automatically. You'll want to look into some sort of client/server communications like WebSockets. https://github.com/websockets/ws

Answer (score 1):

The connection between your express server and react application is not real-time, consequently, your client app won't get any update when the is a change to the data layer. You should take a look at [Socket.io](https://socket.io/), it's a simple real-time engine you can easily integrate into your express app for real-time functionality.